# layout changed once published live

Tags: html, css, layout, centering, publishing

I received help centering an image within a box using a "helper" pseudo element element, which was working until I published it live. I'm not sure what's going on.
you can see whats going on at [live link](http://community.shor-line.com/year-end-sale-2015-main). And this is the code I was using for the layout 

Code:

```css
.offer {
  width: 288px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: solid 3px #19468d;
  height: 310px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}
.price span {
  font-family: avenir next;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #19468d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.price a {
  position: relative;
  font-family: avenir next;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: #19468d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #19468d;
}
.price a:hover {
  color: #19468d;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}
#cost {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px
}
#info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px
}
.box img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 252px;
  vertical-align: center;
}
#grid {
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari 8 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Safari 8 */
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  /* Safari 8 */
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.price {
  text-align: left
}
.price #dollar {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="price">
      <span id="dollar">&#36;</span><span>27</span>
    </div>
    <span class="helper"></span>
    <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/75704/JPs-Slices/2016_Yes/img/floorexammat.jpg">
    <div class="price" id="info">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" id="buy-now">Buy Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: On the live site, the image is centered in the box in the same way as in the snippet here, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Rather use flex for the images. On the ".box" you can do

```
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
```

and remove the helper.